# Parse.com - secure sending data with javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, service

I'm building right now simple game with Angular JS and Parse.com cloud as my database.

My goal is in the and of the game, to store user score inside Parse cloud.

But how can i do this securly, when anyone can get access to my Parse keys, becouse they are visible in my js file, and simply recreate Parse Object with some fake data, and then store it in my database ?

ACL's it's not the point in this particular case - right now i just turn of write acl before save, to prevent users from changing they scores before save.

In my game i don't have any Parse Users - i want to all peaople play my game, without logging in.

What do you think about idea to make '[fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074881/anonymous-users-with-parse-sdk)' user like in first answer in this post ( becouse Anonymous anonymous can't be create in JS parse SDK ), and then track the session and the user ?

Is it even helpful in my case ?

Maybe i should make some check in Cloude Code - like comparison Cookies or local storage data before saving in Parse ( it will make cheating in game harder but still possible ) ?

Below i present my whole service to show you what is all about:

```
angular.module('Parsedb', [])
.provider('Parsedbmanager', function() {
  this.$get = function($q, $http) {

    // new Parse constructor
    var ParseHighScore = Parse.Object.extend('ParseHighScore');

    // create new obj 
    var parseHighScore = new ParseHighScore();

    this.parseInit = function() {
        Parse.initialize('myKey', 'myKey');
    };

    this.setParsedb = function(newScore) {
      // set val
      parseHighScore.set('HighScore', newScore);
      // save score to cloud
      parseHighScore.save(null, {
        success: function (parseHighScore) {

          // protect from change saved obj 
          var acl = new Parse.ACL();
          acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
          acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
          parseHighScore.setACL(acl); 

          return parseHighScore.save();
        },
        error: function (parseHighScore, error) {
          console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
        }
      });
    };

    this.getParsedb = function() {
      // need q to get this asynch
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var query = new Parse.Query(ParseHighScore);
      query.limit(5);
      query.descending("HighScore");
      query.find({
         success: function(results) {
          console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
          // resolve, if you have results
          deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function(error) {
           deferred.reject(error.message);
        }
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    return this;
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you let the user to write to db then there will always be a situation where user can change data .. i think all you can do is, to abstract it from user

Comment: What do you mean by 'abstract from user' ?

Comment: That you don't let them understand what you do